# Jest parametrized test - if condition inside

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I wonder which approach is better. Can I use `if` condition inside tests, or when having these kind of cases, it's better to split them into two `.each` tests?

```
test.each([['Option 1'], ['Option 2']])(
    `WHEN selected %s option THEN parameters section is visible`,
    async (optionName) => {
      const { collectButton } = await initializeTest();
      fireEvent.click(screen.getByText(optionName));

      await expectElementToHaveAttribute(collectButton, 'disabled');
      expect(screen.getByText(parametersSectionHeader)).toBeTruthy();
    },
  );

  test.each([['Option a']])(
    `WHEN selected %s option THEN parameters section is NOT visible`,
    async (optionName) => {
      const { collectButton } = await initializeTest();
      fireEvent.click(screen.getByText(optionName));

      await expectElementNotToHaveAttribute(collectButton, 'disabled');
      expect(screen.queryByText(parametersSectionHeader)).toBeFalsy();
    },
  );
```

```
  test.each([['Option 1', 'visible'], ['Option 2', 'visible'], ['Option a', 'NOT visible']])(
    `WHEN selected %s option THEN parameters section is %s`,
    async (optionName, visibility) => {
      const { collectButton } = await initializeTest();
      fireEvent.click(screen.getByText(optionName));

      if(visibility === 'visible') {
          await expectElementToHaveAttribute(collectButton, 'disabled');
          expect(screen.getByText(parametersSectionHeader)).toBeTruthy();
      } else {
          await expectElementNotToHaveAttribute(collectButton, 'disabled');
          expect(screen.queryByText(parametersSectionHeader)).toBeFalsy();
      }
    },
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

They are supposed to be different tests when it comes to `if`, explicitness is preferred in tests, not to mention that making it a single test doesn't make it much DRYer. In case some piece is reusable, it can be extracted to helper function.

In this case this can be solved by not using test-specific assertions:

```
  test.each([['Option 1', true], ['Option 2', false], /*...*/])(
    `WHEN selected %s option THEN parameters section is %s`,
    async (optionName, visibility) => {
      const { collectButton } = await initializeTest();
      fireEvent.click(screen.getByText(optionName));

      await expectElementToHaveAttribute(collectButton, 'disabled');
      expect(Boolean(screen.getByText(parametersSectionHeader))).toBe(visibility);
    },
  );
```

Comment: Notice two things:

1. I want to have understandable test name e.g. section is not visible, instead of section is false

2. inside `if` condition, I call either `expectElementToHaveAttribute` or `expectElementNotToHaveAttribute`, they're not the same. That's why I can't use your solution with `visibility` flag.

Comment: I see. Use different test params for a label and a value. You can use use some thing instead of expectElementToHaveAttribute, etc that can accept an argument. Otherwise they are efficiently different tests.